# How do I add and rearrange nodes of an XML file in R?

Tags: r, xml, database, dataframe

Below is a subset of an XML file that I have. I would like to add a new element under , but have not been able to get this to work with `addNode()`. How do I add new nodes under `<language>`?

Also, how do I reorder the file so that `<n_cases>` comes immediately before `<definite_source>`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
  <language>
    <name>Old_Irish</name>
    <definite_source>Demonstrative</definite_source>
    <n_cases>5</n_cases>
  </language>
  <language>
    <name>Irish</name>
    <definite_source>Demonstrative</definite_source>
    <n_cases>4</n_cases>
  </language>
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "xml2" package has a simple syntax for adding and removing nodes from an XML document.

To rearrange the structure you first need to locate and copy the nodes you want to move, then remove them from the document and then add original list back into the document.  I would not recommend this unless you have a very specific reason for doing so.

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)

page <- read_xml("<dataset>
  <language>
    <name>Old_Irish</name>
    <definite_source>Demonstrative1</definite_source>
    <n_cases>5</n_cases>
  </language>
  <language>
    <name>Irish</name>
    <definite_source>Demonstrative2</definite_source>
    <n_cases>4</n_cases>
  </language>
</dataset>")

#Find the nodes you want to relocate
nodesdefinite <- page %>% xml_find_all(".//definite_source")
html_structure(page)
#Remove the Nodes
page %>% xml_find_all(".//definite_source") %>% xml_remove()
#Add them where desired
page %>% xml_find_all(".//n_cases") %>% xml_add_sibling(nodesdefinite, .where="after")

#Verify the structure
html_structure(page)
page %>% xml_find_all(".//definite_source")

#To add a node
#Using the add_child, add the new node at the end of the list
page %>% xml_find_all(".//language") %>% xml_add_child("newNode", "new value")
html_structure(page)   #Verify the structure

#Using the add_sibling, better control for placement
page %>% xml_find_all(".//n_cases") %>% xml_add_sibling("newSibling", pi, .where="before")
```